# How to display this data neatly?

Tags: python, pandas

I am printing out a csv file and it comes out looking like this
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvWLH.png)

How do I make all of the columns display next to each other instead of stacked? For example instead of 'CENSUS2010POP' being below 'SUMLEV' I want it to display next to 'CTYNAME'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey since you are printing it in Terminal hence its showing like that. You can try using jupyter notebook. It can be modified as per your requirements.